# scheme-send-region emacs

Tags: emacs, scheme, mit-scheme

I open a .scm file in emacs and I tried to evaluate it in a mit-scheme inferior buffer with the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd> command but, nothing happens. I followed the instructions in the "Starting Scheme in Emacs" section in the page with" http://community.schemewiki.org/?emacs-tutorial.

So when a try to evaluate something directly in the buffer running mit-scheme I see the same behavior: nothings is evaluate when I press enter key. But when I use the interpreter directly in command line works well.

My .emacs file looks like this:

```lisp
;;; Always do syntax highlighting
(global-font-lock-mode 1)

;;; Also highlight parens
(setq show-paren-delay 0
      show-paren-style 'parenthesis)
(show-paren-mode 1)

;;; This is the binary name of my scheme implementation
(setq scheme-program-name "mit-scheme")
```

I have XUbuntu 12.04, emacs23 and mit-scheme 9.1.1.

¿Any idea about the problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

But <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd> open a file in read-only mode. Don't send any buffer to GNU/MIT-scheme interpreter. You need to use <kbd>M</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd> instead of. It will send the current buffer to GNU/MIT-scheme interpreter or <kbd>M</kbd> + <kbd>z</kbd> which send the current expression to evulation.

What I did to have my GNU/MIT-scheme working:

downloaded the [`xscheme.el`](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/mit-scheme/utilities.pkg/xscheme.el) file;

copyed this file to `emacs_location/emacs/version/lisp` directory(note: it must be replace the old file) on my OpenSUSE, the directory is ``/usr/share/emacs/23.3/lisp`.

putted: `(load-library "xscheme")` into my `.emacs` file;

Done! it's installed.. visit a new `.ss` or `.scm` file, type: <kbd>M</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> and then: `run-scheme`. If it's installed you can see the new buffer running `MIT-scheme` interpreter.

Running hello world:

go back to file buffer and write:

```
(display "Hello,world!")
```

and then <kbd>M</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd>:

You will see something like this(sorry for biggest picture, I can't cut it/resize here):

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your time Jack, your answer was really helpful! Now I'm enjoying the M + o shortcut :-)